# Openshift - some requests fail (proxy error)

Tags: node.js, apache, http, proxy, openshift

I'm using openshift to deploy some little applications I built. Everything is ok, but SOMETIMES, don't ask me why, when I try to log-in (post request), I get this error (after waiting 5 minutes more or less):

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request POST /login.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Different requests works, only this post request for logging in seems broken. 
Logs of my application don't show errors, just seem that request is not handled. 
Any advice?

Comment: any idea on this i get this only when i attempt access my admin panel.

Comment: What auth provider are you using?